# The election pages offer an outdated version of OpenSTV

Tags: support, election

Apparently, version 2 of OpenSTV has been released with better Unicode support. However, the download pages still offer version 1.7.1 for Windows and OSX, while the Ubuntu repositories are stuck on 1.6.1.

Could we get updated copies of the program, perhaps including something for Linux? I know it sounds silly to beg for updated copies of a FOSS program of all things, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design -- our agreement with the author specifies that we provide only the version current at the time of the agreement.

I suggest you email him directly if you wish for a different outcome.

Comment: I don't think I for one am personally going to bother. Thanks for the info, though!