Remove the “download OpenSTV for macOS” link from election pages, it is useless
Every election result page (examples: 2024 Moderator Election on Stack Overflow, 2024 Moderator Election on Mathematics SE) prominently displays a box with links to the election data and the suggestion to

... use OpenSTV for Windows or macOS to audit the results.

The macOS application from the download link does not run on current Mac computers. It is a 32-bit Intel application, and these are not supported since macOS Catalina, which was released in 2019.

It has been reported before that this version of OpenSTV is outdated, and that the agreement with its author does not allow to distribute a newer version. Also OpenSTV is now OpaVote, which means that there is probably no up-to-date version of that application available at all.
I suggest to remove the download link for the macOS application from (future) election result pages, because it is useless on all modern Mac computers.
I haven't tested the Windows app myself, but Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog wrote in a comment that “The Windows app still works on modern computers.”

The Windows app still works on modern computers. The only major compatibility issue is ancient 16-bit applications built for OSes earlier than Windows 95, which won't run on 64-bit Windows systems (including Windows 11).

Since the code for 1.7.1 is still out there, I hope someone from SE recompiles it for 64-bit Intel and uploads that version.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Good to know about Windows, thanks for that. – I do not know if/where the code for 1.7.1 is available. As I understand it from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103778/196432, a newer version can not be distributed due to licensing issues.
